# How do you find the asymptotic distribution of the OLS estimator in a simple linear regression model with an intercept?

Tags: asymptotics, regression, least-squares

How do I find the asymptotic distribution of $\beta_1$ in the model $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\epsilon_i$?

I am able to follow [Cameron's derivation](http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/e240a/asymptotic.pdf) of a very similar model without an intercept, but when I try to use the same approach in my model, I run into issues because I can't get the intercept term to go away.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have the expression of the OLS estimator? And which assumptions are you ready to impose?

Comment: @bdx77 I wanted to use $\beta_1 = \sum{x_iy_i}/\sum{x_i^2}$ since that is most intuitive to me. It looks like I may need the alternative formulation where you subtract the means, though. I'm assuming $(y_i, x_i)$ are drawn independently from a joint distribution and that the regressor and the error term are uncorrelated.